# How to fix MRP sequence number

Tags: odoo

I am having a problem with MRP standard module on OpenERP.
The problem is on the sequence number of all manufactoring orders.

If I click on Create button and then Discard button, the manufactory order number increases in sequence. This is happening because the action of achiving the number is on the Create button and not on Save button. So, if I click Create/Discard 10 times, this number will increase 10 times even thinking that none of them were saved.

What I need to do is do add an action on the Save button, to verify on the database what was the last saved number (independently of its state) and add the next number to the manufactoring order I am saving at that moment. This way I will garantee that the manufactoring order number sequence is correct.

Thank you all in advance

Paulo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change few following changes in your file of core module.

- **`addons/mrp/mrp.py`**

In above file first find `class mrp_production` and `_columns = {` and field is `name` **remove required=True and readonly=Ture** and than find `_defaults =` and than comment on `name`.

After than write below `create method.`

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    vals['name'] = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'mrp.production')
    return super(mrp_production, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```

- **`addons/mrp/mrp_view.xml`**

In this file find `<h1>Manufacturing Order <field name="name" class="oe_inline"/></h1>` and replace with this

```
<h1>Manufacturing Order <field name="name" class="oe_inline" readonly="1"/></h1>
```

After than restart your server with upgrade database and module name `mrp`.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: if your problem is solved than you may accept answer and give upvote for this. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Odedra. I have tried exactly the way you instruct but after restart the server I am gettnig a "No handler" error. Perhaps the create method should be write on a specific area of the file? I write it inside the mrp_production class. Any idea?

Comment: yes, you put code is correctly, but their is problem with your server start. You getting error `No handler` because of wrong server start.

Comment: yes Odedra. This error is a problem with server start. If I undo the changes on the addons/mrp/mrp.py and restart the server it works fine. When I add the changes to this file, the server starts (on services) but when accessing it via browser I get this error.

Comment: ohh I don't think so problem with code because as my end it's work fine. Issue with server. Can you please write how you start server?

Comment: I am making this tests on Windows, so there is no specific start server prompt. I just restart OpenERP on works fine. When I try to access the "server" (no database specific), I get this "no handler" error. If I put the file with changes, I get the error, if I replace it with original one, it works. I will try it once again and let you know

Comment: Odedra, I confirm that the problem is on the mrp.py file. After restarting the server, I delete the compiled python file (mrp.pyc) because this is created on the compile process when the server starts. With the changed file, when the server starts does not compile the mrp.py file and do not generate an mrp.pyc file. If I do it with the original file, it works fine. Perhaps I must call the create method from some part of the code?

Comment: The above code is change the database structure of mrp_production table so you need to upgrade with database. I just like ubuntu for `OpenERP coding`. After `_defaults{}`. you can write above create method.

Comment: Yes but you just nedd to start the server with the upgrade modules and database switch if you have a database that uses this module and want to upgrade it on the fly. But if you add this module to a brand new openerp instalation (with no databases) and replace the original module, it should compile the python file so I can install it as a module. I have tested, and id does not work. The python file is not compiled and still get the same "no handler" error.

Comment: Odebra, tested again and all described changes are acceptable. The problem occurs when I add the create method to the file. Any idea? Thank you very much

Comment: As my end their is no error with create method otherwise i will try. Ahead no idea with `Window system. :(`