# openERP current sequence value

Tags: odoo, sequence

Is there by any chance a way to return the current value (without increment) of  sequence in openERP, I've used the "next_by_code" and as it shows it returns the value and increments, I've searched the ir.sequence class and i haven't gotten much use out of it

I'm trying to display the current value of the sequence because implementing the next val with "_defaults" in the creation view keeps incrementing even without creation, if i press create and go back and press create again the value would increase even if i didn't create since the default function is using next_by_code , is there any other way to show the value of the current number without the increment happening?

Comment: this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22690354/how-to-fix-mrp-sequence-number/22705574#22705574

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i went with the traditional way of just hiding the sequence then forcing it into the id with the create method :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information with:

```
def get_current_sequence(self, cr, uid, seq_ids, context=None):
    seq_ids = self.pool.get('ir.sequence').read(cr, uid, seq_ids, ['number_next', 'number_increment'], context=context)
    res = {}

    for seq_id in seq_ids:
        res[seq_id['id']] = seq_id['number_next'] - seq_id['number_increment']

    return res
```